# How does StatefulSet assigns hostname to containers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How does StatefulSet spec in Kubernetes assigns the hostname to each container in case we set `hostNetwork: true`? I have the following spec (similar):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: abc
spec:
  serviceName: abc
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      #hostame: test
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: abc
        image: abc.xyz.com:9001/abc:01.00.00.00
        ports:
        - name: api-port
          containerPort: 9000
          hostPort: 9000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api
            port: api-port
            scheme: HTTPS
```

Now after running the `kubectl create` command, I see that the first container when comes up picks the hostname of the host since we have specified `hostNetwork: true`, but the second container when comes up has hostname something like `abc-0.abc.default.svc.cluster.local`.

- Kubectl version: 1.7.3
- Docker version: 1.12.6

Also, the only service running is the Kubernetes service. I didn't create abc service myself.

`NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   1d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should create only one pod per node, I tested below in my 1.8 cluster, its created one pod per node with correct pod hostname name (same as node name).  it will not create any service we need to create one.

your cluster is version 1.7.3, it may be bug that's why its creating hostname incorrectly.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: abc
spec:
  serviceName: abc
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      #hostame: test
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: sfgtools
        image: sfgroups/alphine_nettools
        ports:
        - name: api-port
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
```

**I have only 2 nodes, its created only two pods**
[image: I have only 2 nodes, its created only two pods]

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, basically StatefulSet creates a pod on each node if there are replicas ? so it's similar to DaemonSet?

Comment: In my case, the pods name is also abc-0 and abc-1 but when I log into the container to check the hostname:
- pod-0 container running on the host `host0` has the hostname `host0`
- pod-1 container running on the host `host1` has the hostname in the pattern `$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local`
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Comment: @SureshVishnoi  Statefull set and DeamonSet both are different, for statefull set we need to have all the resource available on the node to start the pod. Since we defined the port, only one process can bind to that port. If we remove the ports section. It will start all 3 pods in two nodes.

Comment: @sfgroups My bad, I was checking my app's config file to confirm the hostname but it was not clearing up the old config to write a new one. Sorry for the confusion. It is working as you mentioned. I'll accept your answer.